# Basic Python problems. ((self) parameter, for loop and bubblesort)

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
class BubbleSort:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x=[]
    self.limit=0

  def getElements(self):
    self.limit=int(input("Enter the limit:"))
    print("Enter {} number".format(self.limit))
    for i in range(1,self.limit+1):
      self.x.append(int(input()))

  def sort(self):
    for i in range(0,self.limit):
      for j in range(0,(self.limit-1)-i):
          if self.x[j+1] < self.x[j]:
              temp1=self.x[j+1]
              temp2=self.x[j]
              del self.x[j]
              del self.x[j+1]
              self.x.insert(j+1,temp2)
              self.x.insert(j,temp1)
              print(self.x)

    print("Sorted list is")
    for i in self.x:
        print(i)


def main():
  b=BubbleSort()
  b.getElements()
  b.sort()
if __name__=="__main__":main()
```

This is a simple bubble sort program.

Problem 1: If I run the program, two same numbers come , for example, when i enter say -> 3 6 5 1 2

output -> 1 2 2 5 6

The 3 gets replaced by 2.

2: why do I see a lot of 'self' as parameter to a function in python? then what does self.x=[] and self.limit=0 do? 
    I am super new to methods as a concept and I tried reading, they do not help.

3.In the function getElements, what is self.limit ? why is it even required? we can just use a normal variable like 'x' 
Ex: `x= int(input("enter the limit:"))
    print("enter {} number".format(x))`

3.Explain the `self.x.append(int(input())))`
   Doesnt append(int(something)) will add the value of something in the end of a list?

1. Check the for loop, say the self.limit is 5(entered value).  then the loop requires 6 numbers right? equivalence in c++ 
   `for(i=1;i<=6;i++)`
   Assuming the left most number is not considered in python in the range function. right?

Mainly explain 'self' parameter in every function.

Comment: Please break it down into separate questions.

Comment: It looks like you are deleting items from a list as you are iterating over it. You shouldn't do this as it can cause unexpectected results.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete x[j], x[j+1] becomes x[j].  Replace:

```
del self.x[j]
del self.x[j+1]
```

with:

```
del self.x[j+1]
del self.x[j]
```

However, like @IanAuld said, deleting elements of an array while iterating over it is poor programming practice.  Instead, try making a new array and copying the elements to the new array, leaving the original array unchanged in the process.  Afterward, if you want, you can replace the old array with the new array.

And to answer your second question, self refers to the class so you can access other variables from the same class your function is in.  For example, if you have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class Foo:
    bar = 3
    def getValueOfBar(self):
       return self.bar


x = Foo()

print( x.getValueOfBar() )
```

self refers to the parent class, so you can retrieve variables from the class that aren't in the scope of the function.